# On a paper by Dimitrie Pompéiu and on one (in two parts) by Edmund Landau

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, asymptotics, power-series

To celebrate the new year and the future of mathematics (or the mathematics of future), I see no better way to ask a question stemming from my researches on power series.

The two papers the title alludes to are listed in the reference section: in [2] Dimitrie Pompeiu, considering the class of analytic functions $f(z)= a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 +\ldots$ converging on the open disk $\Bbb D(0,R)\subset \Bbb C$ and defining $M(r)=\max_{|z|=r} |f(z)|$, proves that
$$
M(r)\geqq\dfrac45 (|a_0|+|a_1|r)
$$
(In his review Knopp <s>seems to assume</s> assumes $R=r$, <s>which is possibly a typo</s>).
In [1], according to the JFM review by Konrad Knopp, Edmund Landau proves some results from [2] in a simpler way and moreover corrects a wrong result of Carl Cristian Hansen one the growth of the sum $|a_0+a_1+\ldots + a_n|$ as $n\to \infty$ (Landau and Hansen assume obviously $R=1$).

**Question**(**s**)

1. I tried to search for a digital copy of [1] and [2], but I failed: should I ask for a hardcopy to my librarian or was I inaccurate and the papers are already available in digital form?
2. Part of the results of [1] are also found in Landau's *Darstellung* (I consulted the one edited by Dieter Gaier) but unfortunately it seem that those I'm interested in are not: again, am I right or have I missed some "modern" (in a wider sense) references where these result can be found?

**References**

[1] Edmund Landau, "Abschätzung der Koeffizientensumme einer Potenzreihe. I, II" (German) Archiv der Mathematik und Physik, 3 Reihe, 21, 42-50 (1913); 21, 250-255 (1913), [JFM 44.0288.03](https://zbmath.org/44.0288.03).

[2] Dmitrie Pompéiu, "Sur une relation d’inégalité dans la théorie des fonctions holomorphes" (French), Archiv der Mathematik und Physik, 3 Reihe, 19, 224-228 (1912), [JFM 43.0509.01](https://zbmath.org/43.0509.01).

Comment: I believe I have resolved your first question by providing links (and screenshots) for the two references that you mention. (Usually a separate question on MO would involve a separate post). As to finding sources such as these, it is sometime more fruitful to search for the journal and find the specific issue (rather than searching by article name or author). Other than that, aggressive googling can get you far!

Comment: Thank you Benjamin, I cannot access the Hathi Trust, nevertheless the scans are most useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below are **both** references: links then screenshots.

The first reference can be found in full [**here**](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=njp.32101033961994&seq=264).

In case permissions etcetera should change, below are screenshots of the pages:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

The second reference can be found as a PDF [**here**](https://books.googleusercontent.com/books/content?req=AKW5QadutihaWRd5Qq2l2UbTtHVzdLyuPYDXlfkRKitxW8BHgpna9Wlyd4XxKDoF3d8ZnewYWORPBw5-OYfDU7t2CFW4P7u6n0ut-bdcjOrB3eK9awYNb5_uzgI0eBNuOvJD9XUKbeAMHqbbtD0FDcy3wrjbOm5Pq9S-LsgWrYnMS6mJx1mZmjsGqueqj8oeWHgmdb5-k681zvLYnm5B4pXBfzXISnd2FufrUwpV8JzPGYgFNV2yxUfvBARseu24WOWXlbnRVy2ykMwtvG5-V0kdMOLK6v7aPA).

The document begins on PDF 246/404 (p. 224).

In case permissions etcetera should change, below are screenshots of the pages:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I accept your answer of the first part of the question as if it would answer it as a whole. I can award a bounty if there will be someone which answers the second part. Thank you.

Comment: Benjamin, I just found that [the above link](https://books.googleusercontent.com/books/content?req=AKW5QadutihaWRd5Qq2l2UbTtHVzdLyuPYDXlfkRKitxW8BHgpna9Wlyd4XxKDoF3d8ZnewYWORPBw5-OYfDU7t2CFW4P7u6n0ut-bdcjOrB3eK9awYNb5_uzgI0eBNuOvJD9XUKbeAMHqbbtD0FDcy3wrjbOm5Pq9S-LsgWrYnMS6mJx1mZmjsGqueqj8oeWHgmdb5-k681zvLYnm5B4pXBfzXISnd2FufrUwpV8JzPGYgFNV2yxUfvBARseu24WOWXlbnRVy2ykMwtvG5-V0kdMOLK6v7aPA) is unaccessible to me: could you post an alternative?

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Not that I see at the moment, and I couldn't easily make a google books excerpt into a PDF. Luckily, this is why I posted the screenshots! Maybe you can download them, merge as a PDF, and upload that document somewhere for others to access. That's my best idea at the moment...

Comment: Benjamin, nevertheless thank you and do not worry: I'll try something else. I just tried to access the first part of Landau's paper, which was not posted as screenshots.